# How to Use button instead of checkbox when wants to hide or show something(div)

Tags: html, css

instead of checkbox wants to use button for hide and show the div.
Below code for checkbox, adding button instead of checkbox but it is not working.

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
    <h1>Hide the DIV: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck"></h1>
    <div ng-hide="myCheck"></div>
</body>
```

This code is work for only checkbox, i want a button instead of this.

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you want to achieve...the code you're using, HTML, JS...without this is quite hard to help you.

Comment: A checkbox is evaluated as `true` or `false`. You can use a button to toggle the value of a `$scope` variable and set the visibility according to the value of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this to show and hide div on `button` click.

```
<button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">test </button>
<div ng-show="showDiv" >
    hello test
</div>
```

Comment: If it helped can you mark it as correct answer by clicking on tick